# get data from async function to another function React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with async function. I need `track.user` in another function but my func getTracks() async. I don't have clue how can i get this.

```
const Player = ({trackUrl, index, cover, id}) => {
    const [track, setTrack] = useState({})
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const getTracks = async () => {
            await httpClient.get(`/track/${id}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    setTrack(response.data);
                })
        }
        getTracks();
        getUser() // track.user undefined 
    }, [])

    const getUser = async() => {
        await httpClient.get(`/profile/${track.user}/`)
            .then((response) => {
                setUser(response.data);
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a issues here re. async code and how effects should be used. How are you planning to run that `getUser` function? Do you just want it to run on component mount? Or will it be some event handler's function, like when they click a button?

Comment: I want use getUser when component did mount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would declare both functions at the beginning of the component (you can later optimise them with `useCallback` but it's not that important in this phase).

```js
const getTracks = async () => {
  await httpClient.get(`/track/${id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      setTrack(response.data);
    })
  }

const getUser = async() => {
  await httpClient.get(`/profile/${track.user}/`)
    .then((response) => {
      setUser(response.data);
  })
}
```

I would then call an `async` function inside the `useEffect` hook. There are a couple of ways of doing it: you can either declare an `async` function in the `useEffect` hook and call it immediately, or you can call an anonymous `async` function. I prefer the latter for brevity, so here it is:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    await getTracks();
    getUser();
  })();
}, []);
```

Now when you call `getUser` you should be sure that `getTracks` has already set the `track` variable.

Here is the complete component:

```js
const Player = ({trackUrl, index, cover, id}) => {
  const [track, setTrack] = useState({})
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})

  const getTracks = async () => {
    await httpClient.get(`/track/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setTrack(response.data);
      })
    }

  const getUser = async() => {
    await httpClient.get(`/profile/${track.user}/`)
      .then((response) => {
        setUser(response.data);
      })
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await getTracks();
      getUser();
    })();
  }, []);
}
```

#### EDIT 07/18/22

Following [Noel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13753682/noel)'s comments and linked [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-flower-bkw9sy?file=/src/App.js), I figured out that my answer wasn't working. The reason why it wasn't working is that the `track` variable was't available right after the `getTrack()` hook execution: it would have been available on the subsequent render.

My solution is to add a second `useEffect` hook that's executed every time the `track` variable changes. I have created two solutions with jsonplaceholder endpoints, one (see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hawking-r1k2jd)) which preserves the most of the original solution but adds complexity, and another one ([here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-frog-e952w2?file=/src/App.js)) which simplifies a lot the code by decoupling the two methods from the `setTrack` and `setUser` hooks.

I'll paste here the simpler one, adapted to the OP requests.

```js
export default function Player({ trackUrl, index, cover, id }) {
  const [track, setTrack] = useState({});
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const getTracks = async () => {
    // only return the value of the call
    return await httpClient.get(`/track/${id}`);
  };

  const getUser = async (track) => {
    // take track as a parameter and call the endpoint
    console.log(track, track.id, 'test');
    return await httpClient.get(`profile/${track.user}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const trackResult = await getTracks();
      // we call setTrack outside of `getTracks`
      setTrack(trackResult);
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (track && Object.entries(track).length > 0) {
        // we only call `getUser` if we are sure that track has at least one entry
        const userResult = await getUser(track);
        console.log(userResult);
        setUser(userResult);
      }
    })();
  }, [track]);
  return (
    <div className="App">{user && user.id ? user.id : "Not computed"}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `Now when you call getUser you should be sure that getTracks has already set the track variable.`You havnnt done this in your code.The present code calls getUser with empty obj

Comment: Sorry @Noel I don't understand your comment. Is it because I don't pass `track` as a parameter to the `getUser` function? Please notice that the `user` variable is set by the `setUser` function inside `getUser`, and that the `await` keyword before `getTracks` makes sure that `getUser` will only get called once everything in `getUser` will have been executed (including the `setUser` part).

Comment: No my friend.You have a wrong understanding of the await keyword. await doesnt wait for the setUser part. Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-flower-bkw9sy?file=/src/App.js) sandbox console for demo.

Comment: Yes, you're right that my code was incorrect, but the reason is not that the await doesn't wait for the setUser part. Even when the setUser part is executed before, the user is not available to use: it will be on the next render. The solution is to use the `user` variable in a separate `useEffect` hook (as already proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72978943/) answer). [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hawking-r1k2jd) is my sandbox. Thanks for the heads up, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No.I stand by my point that setState has no relation with usage of await whatsoever. setState works asynchronously independently.Your current code is working because you are checking if there are values in object.I need other answerers view on this @Andy

Comment: @Noel I'm not 100% sure that I get your point, but in your first comment, I think you're saying that it's not true that `getTracks()` has executed when I call `getUser()`. Take a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-thunder-gy8wv9?file=/src/App.js:736-754) new sandbox with console.logs: the log after `await getTracks();` is printed after the log at the end of `getTracks`, so the await is really waiting for the complete execution of the function. Let me know if I'm not understanding your point.

Comment: I'm writing with reference to your first comment `await keyword before getTracks makes sure that getUser will only get called once everything in getUser will have been executed (including the setUser part).` the last line isn't true

Comment: Sorry my [last sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-thunder-gy8wv9?file=/src/App.js) wasn't saved when I linked it. Anyway I get your point, I've mismatched the function names, I meant: getUser will only get called once everything in getTracks will have been executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the second request to the `then` block of the dependent first request,i.e., `getTracks`.
Also, you shouldn't mix then and await.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getTracks = () => {
        httpClient.get(`/track/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                setTrack(response.data);
                httpClient.get(`/profile/${response.data.user}/`)
               .then((response) => {
                 setUser(response.data);
               })
            })
    }
    getTracks();
}, [])
```

Comment: I have an error Unexpected reserved word 'await'.

Comment: Because you can't use both then and async-await.

Comment: @Volear You shouldn't use then inside await. I've updated my answer

Comment: Because, in this code, `async` also needs to be on the `then` callback. But really you shouldn't be mixing thenables with async/await code anyway. @Volear

Comment: What's the point of `async` in this code now you've edited it? @NeERAJTK

Comment: @Andy My bad! I've removed it

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be mixing `then`s with `async/await`. You *should* be using another `useEffect` that watches out for changes in the `track` state and then calls `getUser` with that new data.

```js
function Player(props) {

  const { trackUrl, index, cover, id } = props;

  const [ track, setTrack ] = useState({});
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState({});

  async function getTracks(endpoint) {
    const response = await httpClient.get(endpoint);
    const data = await response.json();
    setTrack(data);
  }

  async function getUser(endpoint) {
    const response = await httpClient.get(endpoint);
    const data = await response.json();
    setUser(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) getTracks(`/track/${id}`);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (track.user) getUser(`/profile/${track.user}`);
  }, [track]);

}
```

Comment: `if(track)` inside second useEffect would always return true as state declaration is in object, thus breaking the app.